# Problem with tabular column type m{}

Tags: tables, formatting, vertical-alignment

I've got the following tex code:

```
[...]
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
[...]
\begin{tabular}
    {|m{.465\textwidth}|C{.1\textwidth}|C{.1\textwidth}|C{.1\textwidth}|C{.1\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    & trifft völlig zu & trifft eher zu & trifft eher nicht zu & trifft gar nicht zu \\[10pt]
    \hline
    Das Thema ist für mich wichtig. & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ \\[10pt]
    \hline
    Der Vortragende war kompetent. & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ \\[10pt]
    \hline
    Die mediale Aufbereitung (Folien) war gut. & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ \\[10pt]
    \hline
    Der Vortrag war zu komplex. & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ \\[10pt]
    \hline
    Der Vortrag war fesselnd und lebendig. & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ \\[10pt]
    \hline
    Der Vortrag war verständlich und gut aufgebaut. & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ \\[10pt]
    \hline
\end{tabular}\\[10pt]
```

I would also like and expect that the rightmost column is also vertically centered, but it is aligned at the top.
[image: table]

Does anyone know how to get the rightmost column to be vertically centered?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: using `[...]` makes it harder for anyone to run your example and test the issue, it is always best to include a complete small document. the interpretation of `m` changed in 2018, are you using an old version?

Comment: @campa that was the question that lead to `array` package being updated as noted in the first comment:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know, and in the answer there the update is explicitly mentioned. But technically I still think it's a duplicate, isn't it? For me it is still relevant, because on the university computer we have TeXLive2017 an no chance of update.

Comment: @campa if the OP confirms an old copy is being used then it's a dup, if a new copy is being used then it's  new issue, or the fix added was not good enough, so I'd rather wait for Jasper to confirm which version of the package is being used before closing as dup.

Comment: I'm using the old version (TeXLive 2017), so that should be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

For this table you not need `m` columns, for columns headers rather use `\makecell` from the package of the same name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, makecell}

\begin{document}
{\setcellgapes{5pt}
 \makegapedcells
 \small
 \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| l | *{4}{>{$}c<{$}|} } 
    \hline
    &   \text{\makecell{trifft\\ völlig zu}} 
        &   \text{\makecell{trifft\\ eher zu}}
            &   \text{\makecell{trifft eher\\ nicht zu}}
                &   \text{\makecell{trifft gar\\ nicht zu}}    
                                                        \\
    \hline
Das Thema ist für mich wichtig. 
    & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc      \\ 
    \hline
Der Vortragende war kompetent. 
    & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc      \\    
    \hline
Die mediale Aufbereitung (Folien) war gut.
    & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc      \\
    \hline
Der Vortrag war zu komplex. 
    & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc      \\
    \hline
Der Vortrag war fesselnd und lebendig.
    & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc      \\
    \hline
Der Vortrag war verständlich und gut aufgebaut. 
    & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc  & \bigcirc      \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @bernard, thank you very much for correcting spelling!